# How do I remove the dot at the end of the endpoint in AWS Cloudformation file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

```
  MyPrimaryRecord:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: 2222222222222222
      Name: deneme.slhttnunlu.net
      Type: A
      Failover: PRIMARY
      TTL: '60'
      ResourceRecords:
        - !GetAtt WebServer.PublicIp
      SetIdentifier: Primary
      HealthCheckId: !Ref myHealthCheck

  MySecondaryRecord:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: 2222222222222222
      Name: deneme.slhttnunlu.net
      Type: A
      Failover: SECONDARY
      AliasTarget:
        DNSName: !Select [2, !Split ["/", !GetAtt S3FailBucket.WebsiteURL]]
        EvaluateTargetHealth: false
        HostedZoneId: Z3AQBSTGFYJSTF
      SetIdentifier: Secondary
```

I am trying to write the failover policy feature of the Route53 service with the yaml file, I have completed everything, but the domain routing process does not work due to the "." at the end of the s3 bucket endpoint address. how can I remove the "." at the end of the following address?

```
 slh-route53-ml.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
```

replace(".com.", ".com") I tried to use this feature but I couldn't.

Comment: "I tried to use this feature but I couldn't." - tried exactly how any why it does not work. Any errors?

Comment: I looked up all my `RecordSet`s in all environments - everywhere the `.` at the end. I am guessing there is an issue in another place

Answer (score 0):

According to [AWS Well-architected](https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/well-architected) framework, it is advisable using CloudFront and S3 Origin. That way, an A Record would be as the following:

```
  ARecordE7B57761:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      Name: stage.web-site.us.
      Type: A
      AliasTarget:
        DNSName:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - Distribution830FAC52
            - DomainName
        HostedZoneId:
          Fn::FindInMap:
            - AWSCloudFrontPartitionHostedZoneIdMap
            - Ref: AWS::Partition
            - zoneId
      HostedZoneId: Z06403622UFM115xxxxxx
```

If you host a static website and you want better availability, add the new bucket as an origin and set up a CloudFront origin [group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/high_availability_origin_failover.html).

I hope it leads you finding the solution.